# Angular rest service data changes reflect

Tags: angular, user-interface

I am new in angular js. Currently I'm using angular 6 for my project. I am using http client for rest serice. But it's working as expected. But when rest data value changes / updated then it's not reflected instantly into the browser. Could you please help me.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get(' http://127.0.0.1:5000/getapp_list').subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    //console.log(res);
    this.fetchApp = res['applist'];
    //console.log(this.fetchApp);
  });
}
```

Comment: It's not going to reflect instantly as the values are changing on the backend and Angular is your frontend. You'll have to either use WebSockets or call your API in a `setInterval`.

Comment: You can use backend which returns `Observabe`, For example Firestore.

Comment: You're calling rest service just once on ngOnInit, so it'll give you the data once. If you want to keep getting data after a fix interval of time, you need to write your code in that way. One option is to make use of `setInterval` as suggested by @SiddAjmera